# How to group control properties on actions

Tags: c#, properties, controls, grouping

I have some forms.  On those forms, there can be buttons or other different controls on the heading of the form.  You might imagine an Office toolbar.

Hers' whats triggering my question:
One of my forms is a typical CASE/TASK handling CRM form.  On this form I have a TAB sheet with multiple tabs.  On one of the tabs, I have a listbox containing all documents related to this CASE/TASK.  The current problem is this:  I am going to enable multi selection, meaning that other tools that the user can call from this form will be able to handle multiple documents.  Now, this is not hard to do, but the thing is that when multiple documents are selected I nead to disable some of the controls in the "Office menu".  One way to do this is of course to implement code on the CLICK even on the listbox and count selected and if more than ONE, then disable/enable buttons.
Of course, a simple solution, but then I thought - Hey, this is something Im going to need lots of places.  I then considered writing a class for this, where I could have AddItem method to add the controls, and then this class would have a method to call every time I nead to.

I have considered lots of ways to do this, from using ComponentModel to even implement the System.Action namespace, but I feel Im maybe not on the right track here.  Maybe I just have to create this simple class, maybe not.

Any thoughts...

Comment: I'm a little bit fuzzy on the details, but what you're doing now doesn't sound bad. The list control doesn't know about the behavior of other controls. It just raises an event when its selection changes. Something else that knows about both the list and the other controls (such as the form they're both part of) is responsible for enabling/disabling other controls. Seeing the code you're trying not to duplicate might make it easier to suggest how to package it into something reusable.

Comment: Hi there and thanx for Your reply.

Comment: Yes, And Im thinking of writing a class to do this, but if the class can inherit something usefull it would be Nice. I have no code yet, so nothing to show.  Was just trying to find out if Im on the right track here.  It must be something re-usable,